# how to know about sms alert in IOS 4

Tags: iphone, notifications

I want to alert the user about an sms while my app is running. I am a bit confused if it is possible to get an SMS notification while the app is running. Which API should I use if this is possible?

Comment: AS @BJ Homer said, it's not possible. With few exceptions, apps running on the phone are not allowed to know what other apps are doing. If you find a way to do this, then it's probably a security hole that will be closed as soon as Apple learns of it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with the public API. There is no public API for it.

You might be able to do it via private API on a jailbroken device; I really don't know. If so, keep in mind that you won't be able to ship an app using that API in the app store.

Comment: I have and idea , that when sms/call is coming we can implement application delegate methods for it and it delegate method i should use CoreTelephony frame work to know about the call information , if call state becomes any call State like CTCallStateDialing or CTCallStateIncoming  etc when we would know that it is call other wise it is sms, what do u think?

Comment: I think you are out of luck, because your app won't be notified when a call/sms is incoming in the first place. This idea is a dead end.

Comment: we can do this by this method (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: If your app happens to be running at the time, yes. But users aren't going to just hang around in your app waiting for phone calls to arrive. And realize that willResignActive: is also called when a low battery warning is displayed, or a FaceTime call arrives, or any number of other things. I doubt you'll be able to detect calls reliably enough to build an app around it.